# How do I enable a submit button after a radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi, dynamic-html

I am writing a Perl CGI script.

At first the submit button is disabled, it should be enabled when any of the radio button is selected. A radio button exists for each corresponding row (same name).

Comment: This isn't a perl/cgi question.  However [Enable/Disable Submit Button based on radio buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818415/enable-disable-submit-button-based-on-radio-buttons) may help.

Comment: Yeah you are right @Kenosis, but the thing is that I am doing this with Perl/CGI, you can also use other language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more probably a *JavaScript* question, unless you wan to reload the page with a submit button enabled. But you can *specify* JavaScript events in CGI.

For a radio group, it's just a little trickier. Since the `radio_group` sub allows attributes per item, you just have to specify the same event for each selection.

```
my @values = qw<eenie meenie minie>;
my $enableSubmit 
    = { -onClick => q[document.getElementById('mySubmitButton').disabled = false;] }
    ;
print CGI->radio_group(
      -name       => 'group_name'
    , -values     => \@values
    , -default    => 'meenie'
    , -linebreak  => 'true'
    , -labels     => { map { $_ => ucfirst } @values }
    , -attributes => { map { $_ => $enableSubmit } @values } 
    );
```

Comment: This is very straightforward, so +1. But I think I still prefer to write that HTML/JS out. Do you see an advantage in the `CGI` approach over writing it yourself?

Comment: Only that CGI has a very building-block type of feel. At my old job we used to use Template Toolkit with some customizations for passed CGI blocks. Very easy to get a basic page up and running with CGI. Very easy to get a complex page up and running with TT (and our mods).

Comment: @Axeman this only works with Internet Explorer and does not work with Mozilla Firefox.